# Drupal 7 Sending mail

Tags: drupal-7, batch-processing, mailjet

How do I resolve an error like this:

> An AJAX HTTP error has occurred. HTTP status code: 504 Debug
>   information below. Path: / batch? Id = 42186 & op = do StatusText:
>   error ResponseText: 504 Gateway Timeout 504 Gateway Timeout nginx

In Drupal 7. I have used Batch API to send an email on our user's and Mailjet module.

Comment: What extra details are logged to the server's error_log?

Comment: This is the error that i seen in error reports : 
**Could not call service background_batch:42210 for callback _background_batch_process**
I have don't understand the origin of this error. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you access the AJAX URL directly, say, in a web browser? You should be able to get the URL from the Network tab in Web Developer Tools (use F12 to open them, and reload any page that encounters the error.)